# Generics.Collections.TList<T>.Move source needed

Tags: delphi, generics, move, tlist

Unfortunately, TList in Generics.Collections of Delphi 2009 lacks Move method. I'm in a desperate need of it. Could someone please post it here for me from later versions?

I intend to use it in a descendant class.

Comment: I don't know about the legality of that. Maybe try taking a look at freepascal's `TList.Move` source.

Comment: *Please post copyrighted code here for me* is not an appropriate question for this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement it like so:

```
procedure TMyList<T>.Move(CurIndex, NewIndex: Integer);
var
  Item: T;
begin
  Item := Self[CurIndex];
  Delete(CurIndex);
  Insert(NewIndex, Item);
end;
```

Comment: That implementation will not work for `TObjectList<T>`.

Comment: @StefanGlienke `TObjectList<T>` <> `TList<T>`... I don't see anyone asking about the former.

Comment: I mentioned this because it was asked for the `Generics.Collections.TList<T>` implementation which is different from the one shown and does not break for an object list. Maybe he wants to use that also for object lists. Sorry for thinking further than the question...

Comment: @StefanGlienke It's a valid point, surely.  I was just making clear that it should not be expected of any implementation to work for arbitrary extensions thereof - it answers the question and is exactly as complex as it needs to be to get the job done.  That's good code, in my books.  As we've previously established, copying Emba's code verbatim is not a viable option and, since it is not needed in this context, it doesn't do to burden the answer with it in any case.

Comment: @Stefan I had thought about that. I'm not sure it's possible to implement from the outside when objects are owned. Is there an extract by index?

Comment: Instead of in indexed "Extract", simply setting OwnsObjects before and after the Delete would do too, but only in the descendent class, i.e. not in `TList<T>`

Comment: My sarcasm detector is not completely broken, though. <g>

Comment: @Rudy Your sarcasm detector is broken. That was sincere.

Comment: Oh, sorry, then it is broken indeed. I thought that my solution was a little too obvious.